# Compress and encode a alphanumeric string to a alphanumeric string in Java

Tags: java, compression, encode

Actually I need to send one string to server where it only takes string of size 15 or less. I have one String of length 32 or 36 but this string only contains alpha-numeric character. Now I want to compress the string to 15 character long with alphanumeric character only.

One option also I am seeing as that convert to BigInteger but that also does not shrink the size as expected of 15

Is this possible in Java? Is there any library I can use. I really need the help to do that

Comment: You want to compress an arbitrary string of length 32 to a string of length 15 using the same range of characters? Not possible. For the same reason you can't compress two bits into one bit.

Comment: I remember seeing a simple compression scheme that would take three alphanumeric characters and compress it into two bytes. But that is as good as I remember seeing.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood for your input. I am trying to find a solution using base64 may be it is possible. I am trying to find that solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend your target alphabet to include certain N>0 other chars, then you can encode an input string with fewer characters than it originally had.
Then you can encode a couple of chars from the source alphabet, with a single char from the target alphabet.

You can use the following packages based on your requirements

```
package com.binaryheart.common.comparator;
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compress alphanumerics (upper case, lower case, and digits, 62 in total), represented in bytes, by a factor of two. The most you can get is a smidge better than a 25% reduction. So you can reduce 32 bytes to 24 bytes, or 36 bytes to 27 bytes. The result is binary data.

The fastest approach is to code each character into six bits. That also gives you two more characters you can add to your allowed set to bring it up to 64. Then it is trivial to pack four such characters (6 bits each) into three bytes (24 bits).